# solve_ivp differential equation solver, way to not integrate all return values?

Tags: python, function, return-value, solver, differential-equations

Hey i have a model which gives diferential return values. But also a value which isnt a differential (z)

```
def model(t, f):
x = f[0]
y = f[1]
dx_dt = 2x*y
dy_dt = x**3
z = 2*x

return dx_dt, dy_dt, z
```

My solver can solve this equations and give me x and y at the respective time values.

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
f0 = [2, 1, 0]
result = solve_ivp(model, [np.min(t), np.max(t)], f0, t_eval=t)
```

But now i want also my solution for z which should NOT be integrated by the solver. Is there any possibility to just integrate the first 2 values of my solver? But not the third?

Comment: Why not just compute it after integration, `x,y = result.y; z=2*x`?

Comment: because its bad practise in my opinion to integrate something which should not be integrated, in complex situations the solver could make problems which would be annoying because of something you dont want to be integrated anyways. Is there maybe any solution by wrapper functions or something like that. Im new in programming in general.

Comment: Yes of course, I meant that you do that while reducing the ODE system to just the proper ODE in x and y, leaving z completely out of the integration.

Comment: so with your solution i have to write the whole code 2 times, but i want to avoid this by just not giving my solver the last return value

Comment: Here is my code, i want to get the last value CO2%, but dont want to integrate it, the problem is that its dependend from other values within the function which are also dependend from other values which are changing over the time

Answer (score 0):

You have the situation where the ODE function could be written as

```
def model(t,u):
    v = f(t,u)
    du = g(t,u,v) # v may contain components of du that get simply copied
    return du
```

and you are additionally interested in a quantity `z=h(t,u,v)`. All variables can also be tuples or vectors. Presently the functions stand for code blocks, but in many cases they can also be easily separated out as functions. Thus the first variant would be just to do that, so that the ODE function has minimal extra functionality, and the values `z` are computed at the end from the solution values.

Another variant, if transforming the code blocks to separate functions appears not optimal, you can also construct the model function as in the question,

```
def model(t,u):
    v = f(t,u)
    du = g(t,u,v) # v may contain components of du that get simply copied
    z = h(t,u,v)
    return du,z
```

Then in the call of the solver you use a lambda expression to separate out the derivatives vector

```
result = solve_ivp(lambda t,u: model(t,u)[0], t[[0,-1]], f0, t_eval=t)
```

and from the result by calling the same model function again you get

```
z = model(t,result.y.T)[1]
```

or use an iterator formulation if the model function can not be automatically vectorized

```
z = [ model(t_,u_)[1] for t_, u_ in zip(t,result.y.T) ]
z = np.array(z).T # to get the same index ordering as in result.y
```

Use appropriate array slicing operations if the model function returns just one list of values and not a pair of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thank you for your solution. i think this solution may also work:

```
def model(t,y):

global inner_func
def inner_func(t,y):
    
    #differential Eq System

    return dx_dt, dy_dt, z

dx_dt, dy_dt, z = inner_func(t,y)
return dx_dt, dy_dt

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
f0 = [2, 1, 0]
result = solve_ivp(model, [np.min(t), np.max(t)], f0, t_eval=t)

z = np.array([inner_func(t[i], result[i,:]) for i in range(len(t))])[:,2]
```